# Javascript Function is not Called onclick() and onsubmit()

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone tell me why below javascript functions are not calling while clicking the button or submitting the form.

I am not getting wht is the wrong with this code. Please help

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

function confrm()
{
 alert("check1");
 if(confirm("Are you going to submit this form?")==true)
 {
  return true;
 }
 else
 {
  return false;
 }
}

function checkfrm()
{
 var selcteddate=document.newrequest.sel.value;
 var sdate=new Date(selcteddate);

alert("check 2");

 if(document.newrequest.server.value=="select")
 {
  alert("Select server");
  return false;
 }

 else
 {
  return true;
 }
}

</script>




<form id="newrequest" name="newrequest" method=post action="cgi-bin/newrequest.cgi" onsubmit="return checkfrm();">

<td colspan=2>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return confrm();" />
</td>
```

Comment: Have you actually tried your own code snippet? It works fine for me.

Comment: If it doesn't work for you in the "real" code, open the browser's error console. It's likely that you have syntax errors possibly somewhere else in the code that stops the script execution.

Comment: Snippet works for me as well

Comment: @rajarshi where is `document.newrequest.sel.value` coming from? Can you post the rest of the form code here?

Comment: Here it works fine but I can imagine the document.newrequest will break some browsers.

Comment: I have not pasted the whole code, I just portion where I used those JS function. All tags have been properly closed in the code.

Comment: one more thing, will it bring any issue if I use multiple JS code within multiple <script type=text/javascript></script> tag ?

Comment: @Moogs, i have used a JS calender here.

Comment: btw when click `submit` I can see 'alert("check1");' is executing

Comment: and redirect to `cgi-bin/newrequest.cgi` which is not working on my machine

Comment: I am not sure why it is saying confrm() & checkfrm() undefined. I have used the JS calender and this two function in different script tag, I believe that is creating the issue.

Comment: Thanks god. I got the error & fixed. It was because of a missing " inside the code.

Comment: Yeah, learning to use the browser's console would help a lot with debugging in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it without return. Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confrm(){
        alert("check1");
        if(confirm("Are you going to submit this form?")==true) {               
            document.getElementById("newrequest").submit();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>
<form id="newrequest" name="newrequest" method="post" action="cgi-bin/newrequest.cgi" onsubmit="checkfrm();">
<td colspan=2>
<input value="Submit" type="input" onclick="confrm();" />
</td>
```

You can find the guide for onclick event on 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp
and Submit guide on
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp

Comment: Please don't reference W3Schools. Use the relevant specification for authoritative advice and MDN for examples.

Comment: Removing the return will only make it impossible to block the form submit.